# How to disable other dropdowns until first dropdown is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My project requires users to select Name first before selecting any other dropdowns. To accomplish this, how can I disable other columns until Name column is selected? Please see fiddle and code below.

Here is the code I am working on. I have also included link to my fiddle. Thanks.
https://jsfiddle.net/mL9f58wg/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table-wrap').hide();
var table = $('#example').DataTable({

responsive: true,
mark: true,
stateSave: false,
searching: true
});

buildSelect(table);
$('#table-filter').on('change', function () {
// show the tbody when the user clicks on a filter option
$('#table-wrap').show();
table.columns.adjust();

table.search(this.value).draw();
});


table.on('draw', function() {
buildSelect(table);
});
$('#test').on('click', function() {
table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
$('#table-wrap').hide();
});
});

function buildSelect(table) {
var counter = 0;
table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
var column = table.column(this, {
search: 'applied'
});
counter++;
var select = $('<select id="dd' + counter + '"><option value="">Select</option></select>')
.appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
.on('change', function() {
var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
$(this).val()
);

column
.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
.draw();
});

column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');

});

// The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
var currSearch = column.search();
if (currSearch) {
// Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
// This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
}
});
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>
<div class="searchbox" select id="table-filter">
<p><label for="dd1">Name:</label> <span id="dropdown1" input type="checkbox">
</span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd2">Postion:</label> <span id="dropdown2">
</span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd3">Office:</label> <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
<button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
<div id="table-wrap">
<table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Office</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Start date</th>
<th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>


<tbody>
<tr>
<td>ID.AI</td>
<td>System Architect</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>61</td>
<td>2011/04/25</td>
<td>$3,120</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Garrett -2</td>
<td>Director</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>63</td>
<td>2011/07/25</td>
<td>$5,300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
<td>Technical Author</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>66</td>
<td>2009/01/12</td>
<td>$4,800</td>
</tr>


</tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add a class to the other pulldowns and set it to display: none, when name pulldown has changed to a value set display to block for the added class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the fields to hide on document load, then attach an event listener to the first box and check the value that the user selects and if it is an actual name show the other two boxes and if not hide them

```js
// Place this whole code block in $(document).ready()

$("span#dropdown2").hide()
$("span#dropdown3").hide()
  
$('span#dropdown1').on('change', function(event) {
  const check = !!event.target.value
  if (check) {
    $("span#dropdown2").show()
    $("span#dropdown3").show()
  } else {
    $("span#dropdown2").hide()
    $("span#dropdown3").hide()
  }
});
```