# Multiple dropdowns, how to disable until first dropdown is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working on a page with a datatable with dropdown menus for filtering. The requirement is to select the "Name" first before selecting any other dropdown. For this purpose, I want to disable other dropdowns until Name has been selected. Also, when the user selects Clear Filters, it should have the same behavior. (Name column enabled and other columns disabled). How can I do this?

Please see the link to jsfiddle and code below. Thanks.
Here is the code I am working on. https://jsfiddle.net/mL9f58wg/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table-wrap').hide();
var table = $('#example').DataTable({

responsive: true,
mark: true,
stateSave: false,
searching: true
});

buildSelect(table);
$('#table-filter').on('change', function () {
// show the tbody when the user clicks on a filter option
$('#table-wrap').show();
table.columns.adjust();

table.search(this.value).draw();
});


table.on('draw', function() {
buildSelect(table);
});
$('#test').on('click', function() {
table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
$('#table-wrap').hide();
});
});

function buildSelect(table) {
var counter = 0;
table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
var column = table.column(this, {
search: 'applied'
});
counter++;
var select = $('<select id="dd' + counter + '"><option value="">Select</option></select>')
.appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
.on('change', function() {
var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
$(this).val()
);

column
.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
.draw();
});

column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');

});

// The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
var currSearch = column.search();
if (currSearch) {
// Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
// This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
}
});
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>
<div class="searchbox" select id="table-filter">
<p><label for="dd1">Name:</label> <span id="dropdown1" input type="checkbox">
</span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd2">Postion:</label> <span id="dropdown2">
</span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd3">Office:</label> <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
<button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
<div id="table-wrap">
<table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Office</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Start date</th>
<th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>


<tbody>
<tr>
<td>ID.AI</td>
<td>System Architect</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>61</td>
<td>2011/04/25</td>
<td>$3,120</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Garrett -2</td>
<td>Director</td>
<td>Edinburgh</td>
<td>63</td>
<td>2011/07/25</td>
<td>$5,300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
<td>Technical Author</td>
<td>San Francisco</td>
<td>66</td>
<td>2009/01/12</td>
<td>$4,800</td>
</tr>


</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: What was wrong with [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75750476/1955268) to your [earlier similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75749726/how-to-disable-other-dropdowns-until-first-dropdown-is-selected)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable other dropdowns until first dropdown is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75749726/how-to-disable-other-dropdowns-until-first-dropdown-is-selected)

Comment: The accepted answer in that link hides the dropdowns. I want to disable them. Also, it doesn't work on Reset Filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
$(document).on('change', '#dd1', function() {
  $('#dd2, #dd3').prop("disabled", false);
})

$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {
  selectDisable();
})

function selectDisable() {
  $('#dd2, #dd3').prop("disabled", true);
}
```

And call the function `selectDisable()` on load.

## Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table-wrap').hide();
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({

    responsive: true,
    mark: true,
    stateSave: false,
    searching: true
  });

  buildSelect(table);
  $('#table-filter').on('change', function() {
    // show the tbody when the user clicks on a filter option
    $('#table-wrap').show();
    table.columns.adjust();

    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });


  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
    $('#table-wrap').hide();
  });
  selectDisable();
});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select id="dd' + counter + '"><option value="">Select</option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
      select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');

    });

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
      // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}

$(document).on('change', '#dd1', function() {
  $('#dd2, #dd3').prop("disabled", false);
})

$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {
  selectDisable();
})

function selectDisable() {
  $('#dd2, #dd3').prop("disabled", true);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>
<div class="searchbox" select id="table-filter">
  <p><label for="dd1">Name:</label> <span id="dropdown1" input type="checkbox">
</span>
  </p>

  <p><label for="dd2">Postion:</label> <span id="dropdown2">
</span>
  </p>

  <p><label for="dd3">Office:</label> <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
  </p>
  <button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
<div id="table-wrap">
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>&#160;</th>
        <th>&#160;</th>
        <th>&#160;</th>
        <th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>ID.AI</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett -2</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$4,800</td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```